# jquery throwing error on @font-face

Tags: jquery, css, font-face

i'm working on a project locally, and am receiving a jquery error on my @fontface.

here's my error:

jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:9000/ostrich-regular-webfont.woff2

here's my working dir:

```
src
| -img
| -scripts
| -styles
     -main.css
     -fonts
          -font files are here
| -index
```

my @font-face:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ostrich_sansmedium';
src: url('ostrich-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('ostrich-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('ostrich-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('ostrich-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('ostrich-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('ostrich-regular-webfont.svg#ostrich_sansmedium') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

i've tried different variations of the url, including:

```
 url('fonts/ostrich-regular-webfont.svg#ostrich_sansmedium'),
 url('styles/fonts/ostrich-regular-webfont.svg#ostrich_sansmedium')
```

etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You sure it's jquery throwing this error? What's the error? 404?

Comment: maybe you don't have that font file

Comment: i double checked, i definitely have all fonts in the right folder. i downloaded the fonts and the @font-face declarations from fontsquirrel.com

Comment: Just to confirm, your variation is correct. You need to point it to the `fonts` directory first. Since that isn't working, take a look at my answer.

Comment: I checked in my hosting - working http://szsi.com.ua/page/site-2/ and path font url('fonts/name_font')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see these kinds of errors with font files a lot when IIS hasn't been correctly configured. If you're *sure* the file is there (the path in your attempt to fix it looks correct), then it could be that IIS is unsure on how to serve these files up (i.e. they'll 404 because the user can't download them, since IIS won't serve them). In your `web.config` file, add the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
```

Obviously the `mimeMap` entry will sit within whatever of it's parent nodes already exist, and you must close them. I've just included that to help you work out where it goes.

Comment: okay. i'm still a bit of a newb, does the web.config file go in the root directory?

Comment: Yep, it usually does. What are you using to build the site at the moment?

Comment: mithril.js, gulp, browserify

Comment: I don't know anything about those I'm afraid. Although - a good way to be tell whether it's a 'serving' problem rather than a broken path or reference would be to try and navigate straight to it. http://localhost:9000/fonts/ostrich-regular-webfont.woff2 - click that - do you reach the font?

Comment: i receive a "cannot GET" error. so it must be a serving issue...? in that case, should i create a web.config file?

Comment: Sounds like it. I don't want to advise you to create a web config file because I'm not sure on the stuff you're using to build it at the moment - don't want to send you on a wild goose chase. I'll have a read around for you...

Comment: yeah, gulp set it up. i'm also receiving a 404 whenever i try to import files into my LESS stylesheet (ex - defaults.less), so it's definitely something to do with my server. not sure if this helps, too, but this is the boilerplate i'm running off of:

https://github.com/velveteer/mithril-boilerplate

Comment: Until I fully understand your set-up I might not be the best person to answer this, sorry. Bit confused on how the whole thing has set up a web server. I think you're right though, it's a server thing. Any odd kind of file extension 404'ing unexpectedly is usually a mime type issue. In IIS (the Windows version of a local web server), you can either configure it through the IIS UI, or you can add stuff to your web config file and IIS automatically picks up on it (hence this answer). But that's pretty useless to you I suppose. Whatever's in charge of your server config/set-up needs amending.

Comment: okay, thanks for the point in the right direction! 

i don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer, but i'll post once i get a chance to look at my server config

Comment: Don't worry, thought it was a quick win anyway. If it was IIS it would've been an easy one. I'm not a fan of having these sorts of problems that stop you from gettin on with development. Good luck. I think I recognised your picture from a dev tweet on twitter btw (No creeper!!). Think you posted something related or your account was recommended because it was related to someone else I have on there.

Comment: trust me, i'm not a fan either haha. that's funny i was recommended on twitter! the twittersphere is a surprisingly small place